# Reading a sitemap.xml file from s3 bucket using nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Here's how I expected it to work:

```
location sitemap.xml {
    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/sitemap.xml;
}
```

Here's how I managed to get it to work:

```
location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
    rewrite ^ /<bucket>/sitemap.xml break;
    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```

There has to be a better way! Enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You had a very minor issue

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/sitemap.xml;
}
```

`=` will make sure the `/sitemap.xml/abc` is not allowed. And `/` was actually required at the start

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I have several sitemap files. Here is my proposition from yours @jpswade :

```
location ~ \.xml$ {

    rewrite ^ /<bucket>/sitemap$request_uri break;
    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```

It works, of course.